# how to read hidden text in python by using selenium?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I use selenium in python to read table data from a website. I want to get `data1` and `data2`.
I use the code like below. But I can only get the data2, the first code will print nothing. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you.

```py
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td.el-table_1_column_1.is-hidden div')
print(elem.text)
```

```py
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td.el-table_1_column_2 div')
print(elem.text)
```

```
<td class="el-table_1_column_1   is-hidden">
    <div class="cell">data1</div>
</td>
<td class="el-table_1_column_2  ">
    <div class="cell">data2</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `elem.get_attribute("textContent")` to get the hidden value from node.

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td.el-table_1_column_1.is-hidden div')
print(elem.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Please check the following [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)